# Junit-check for equality of array of unique class

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I am new to junit & testing. I have two arrays which consist of objects of class type **MyUniqueClass**. I consider the two arrays to be equal if they have the same elements at the same positions. Also, I have overridden the equals() method for my unique class.

I want to check for equality of these two arrays in junit. I could not find any method in the API - http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html How do I do check for the equality in junit ?

**EDIT:**

When I run my junit test to compare the arrays, I get the error:

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected: com.test.IntegerRange<[210, 210]> but was: com.test.IntegerRange<[210, 210]>
    at org.junit.internal.ComparisonCriteria.arrayEquals(ComparisonCriteria.java:50)
    at org.junit.Assert.internalArrayEquals(Assert.java:473)
```

Thanks !

Comment: The message tells you exactly what you need to know: the arrays are different. Meaning: if you call arrayOne[0].equals(arrayTwo[0]); the result is false. Long story short: you think that those two elements are identical, and you assume that your equals() implementation is correct. But well, if that would be the case, you would not run into this error message. The core thing to understand is: you should believe compiler and assert messages **more** than you believe in your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look a little closer.  In the page you linked to, I found this:

```
 public static void assertArrayEquals(java.lang.String message,
                                 java.lang.Object[] expecteds,
                                 java.lang.Object[] actuals)
                          throws org.junit.internal.ArrayComparisonFailure
```

Comment: Hank, that does not work. Please see my edited comment.

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore, it looks like you need to check your IntegerRange.equals() method.  If you didn't override it, it will not compare the fields of IntegerRange--it will only return true if they are the same instance

Comment: Can you share the IntegerRange code you are referring to?

Comment: As a sanity check, you might try `Assert.equals(expectedArray[0],testedArray[0])`